# Cast a pointer to the only class data member type to a class pointer

Tags: c++

Say I have

```
T rawData;
class A {
public:
  T data; // the only data member
  void process(void);
  // more methods;
};
```

What would be the safest way to `A* ptr = (A*) &rawData;` in order to use `ptr->process();` and other methods?

The above approach works, but some compilers warn on strict aliasing rules being violated. Of course, it's safe to create an instance of `A`, set `data` and then retrieve it back after all the processing - but that's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: The safest way to shoot yourself in the leg, huh?

Comment: Related: [can I cast between an aggregate type with one member and that member's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63456999/11082165)

Comment: Why do you want a pointer at all? Or are you asking about member function pointers??

Comment: You don't need pointers for this make data private, and provide a getter.  `class A{ public: T& data() noexcept { return data; }  const T& data() const noexcept {  return data; };` Anyway don't try to outsmart yourself to safe a bit on typing.

Comment: @Alexey S. Larionov Looking for some "approved" way :)

Comment: @Brian61354270 - close, but vice versa: T holds data for stuff similar to a big number implementation, most of the data are read from binary files. The class just implements methods to manipulate on those large data.

Comment: Make A a "borrowing" wrapper.  `class A { T& obj; public: A(T& obj_) : obj{obj_} {} void process(); /*...*/ };`  Then you can `T data; A a{data}; a.process();` your heart out.

Comment: @Eljay Thank you! That's better than the answer I already accepted. I just wonder why my own earlier experiments on this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> some compilers warn on strict aliasing rules being violated

And they are absolutely correct. The solution, that they will accept:

```
A* ptr = new (&rawData) A;
```

However if you make `void A::process()` a free function `void process(T& data)`, it will be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you! Finally I see the use for "placement new". Creating a static process() method is possible but is not so elegant as there is a lot of other methods in the class, some work with references to other instances o the same class - re-writing al that in ol'plain C looks ugly.

Comment: You may place free functions in a namespace, say `namespace A`.